# How prove this diophantine equation $3^x-2^y=k$ have finitely many integral solutions

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

> For any $\forall k\in N^{+}$ show that the diophantine equation $3^x-2^y=k$ have  finitely many integral solutions.

**My try**: if $k=2m$,then
$$3^x=2^y+k=2^y+2m$$ It is clear there is no integer solution,

But for 
$k=2m+1$, I can't prove three finitely many integral solution.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a result of Størmer's theorem.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Størmer's_theorem

Comment: Hello,Thank you,can you find somepaper reseacher this problem,I find sometime,I can't find paper.

Answer (score 3):

This is a result of a theorem due to Carl Størmer.  His theorem can be stated as follows:

Let $S=\left\{ p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_j^{e_i} \mid e_i \in \mathbb{N}_0 \right\}$, where $p_1$, $p_2 \cdots p_j$ is a finite collection of prime numbers.  Then there are a finite number of pairs $x,y \in S$ such that $x-y=k$ (for fixed $k$).

Unfortunately, the wikipedia page for the theorem only considers the $k=1$ case, when in fact Størmer had proven it for *all* integer values of $k$.

Sources:

1. http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1256067456
2. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Størmer's_theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%B8rmer%27s_theorem)

Comment: It's not immediately clear how $k=1$ could have any solutions, since $S$ would be a single-element set...

Comment: Ah, oops, inconsistent variables.  This is what happens when I'm running low on sleep..

Comment: Hello,this theorem how prove it?

Comment: @math110 Check the first link, an article titled "On a problem of Stormer" by D. Lehmer.  Also I have heard of an article titled "A generalization of the Stormer theorem and some applications" which I have not read, but it sounds promising.  These should provide constructive proofs.

Comment: Does stormers theorem guarantee that there exist solutions, or only that there can be at most a finite number of them?

Comment: @abiessu Stormer's theorem guarantees that there are at most a finite number of solutions, and provides method to construct every solution.